# Updating of the ILNumerics surface graphics

Tags: ilnumerics

I'm currently using an ILPlotCube object to display a surface which is generated from user data and I have created a context menu and added options to change some of the plot settings such as the colourmap, lighting etc. The problem I am having is getting the graphics of the plot to update automatically once a change has been made; as it stands the only way I can update the added lights or changed colourmap is by invoking one of the many mouse events on the plot object. I have searched through the ILPlotCube, ILSurface and ILScene classes and can not find any functionality which would seem to do this (I originally thought the Reset() method of the ILPlotCube class would do what was required but it actually does not). Does anybody have any more information about the updating of the graphics and possibly a potential solution?

Comment: Oh and I am using ILNumerics 3.2.0 and C# in a WPF project in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Could you post some code please ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nYqUv66C http://pastebin.com/9U5Pb033 @HaymoKutschbach here are two methods which are to update the plot after a change on the particular setting. Both methods are called from Mouse event handlers and both only update the changes made when I ran my cursor over the plot, rotate it, zoom etc.

Answer (score 1):

Mouse events on nodes in ILNumerics provide arguments of ILMouseEventArgs. The type provides the Refresh property. Set this to true in your mouse event handler. It will trigger a redraw after all events are processed:

```
void iILNode_MouseClick(object sender, ILMouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.DirectionUp) {
        //modify scene here
        // .. 
        // trigger redraw of the scene
        e.Refresh = true; 
    }
}
```

The documentation on mouse event handling: http://ilnumerics.net/mouse-events.html

Comment: Thank you, however this didn't quite work out cause of the way the events were set up; the initial ILMouseEvent brings up a context menu, a selection on a context menu item invokes a System mouse event. However this problem has been solved by simply calling Refresh() on the ILPanel host.